# Identify Torus shaped planet by its residents.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose there is a torus shaped planet. Is it possible to identify its shape by its residents?
What about the other three dimensional objects?
Can we divide the class of three dimensional objects which can be identified and which are not?

Comment: You can try to distinguish between living on a sphere and living on a torus by checking whether the Heawood graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph) can be drawn on your planet. At least, you can use this to confirm that you're living on a torus, but it's unclear how you would use this to confirm that you're living on a sphere.